# Как получить handle окна, зная только имя образа в диспетчере задач?

Tags: winapi, c++

Нужно узнать hwnd окна браузера, но FindWindows не подходит, потому что там меняется заголовок постоянно, а имя класса я не знаю. Я знаю только то, что имя образа в диспетчере задач указано как k-meleon. Какие есть варианты? Желательно с примером.
**UPD:** В принципе я уже взял заголовок из исходников браузера, но все ровно было бы интересно увидеть решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. определяется PID для "имени образа"
2. перебираются окна верхнего уровня
3. для каждого окна делается вызов [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx)

`dwProcessId`, совпадающий с PID для "имени образа" говорит Вам о том, что данное окно порождено Вашим "образом". Если нет других с таким же PID, значит это Ваше искомое окно. Если есть - включайте аналитику, которая поможет Вам найти среди этих окон процесса главное.

> В принципе я уже взял заголовок из исходников браузера

Отличный вариант, заказчику хватит, остальное - лирика.